# Hide cells dependant on what is in a title cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a button that can hide cells when pressed. However I need it to hide different cells dependant on what is the title of the form. I was trying to create a range of these cells and altering the Number Format to hide them, the idea worked before the addition of the if statements.

```
If "G1" = "Pitot" Then
  Range("C10,C11,C79,H48,H49,H50,H55,H61").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;"
End If
If "G1" = "DP Flow Transmitter" Then
  Range("C9,C10,C11,C58,H37,H48,H55,H61").Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = ";;;"
End If
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You are comparing two strings. You have to compare the cell-value with a string.

Comment: Just like @etalon11 mentioned, "G1" should be **Range("G1")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options like this are often best served by a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx).

```
Select Case Range("G1").Value
    Case "Pitot"
        Range("C10,C11,C79,H48,H49,H50,H55,H61").NumberFormat = ";;;"
    Case "DP Flow Transmitter"
        Range("C9,C10,C11,C58,H37,H48,H55,H61").NumberFormat = ";;;"
    Case Else
        'do nothing
End Select
```

Note that [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) is the property being evaluated.